# Uncountable Set of Poles?

Tags: z-transform, transfer-function, poles-zeros

It is easy to define an (ideal) LTI system that would have an infinite number of poles - for instance, if the transfer function is
$$
H(z)=\frac{1}{\cos(z)-1}
$$
However, this would only define a countably infinite set of poles.

I am curious: are there systems with **uncountably** infinite sets of poles?
I would guess that the very definition of a pole would prohibit a function from having a contiguous region of poles, but what about a hypothetical transfer function that would have its poles defined on something like Cantor set?

Comment: Can you define an analytic function that is zero for a contiguous segment of $x$ having non-zero measure and is non-zero outside of that contiguous segment?

Comment: Wow that's an interesting idea with the Cantor set. I guess one could as well ask the question about zeros instead of poles.

Comment: It seems to me that it is possible to have a non-negative and $C_\infty$ function that vanishes only on the Cantor set.

Comment: isn't the Cantor set a countably infinite set of points?

Comment: @robert No, being uncountably infinite is one of the most important properties of the Cantor set.

Comment: i remember the Cantor function, which is continuous, has zero derivative **almost everywhere** (which is everywhere except a countable set of points, each point having zero measure), and increases from $0$ to $1$ in the $0 \le x \le 1$ interval.  now, i thought that the Cantor set are the discrete points between pairs of *"flat"* portions of the Cantor function.

Comment: @robert "almost everywhere" does not mean "everywhere except a countable set of points" - say, almost every point in a circle is inside its boundary, but the circle's boundary itself is an uncountable set of points.

Comment: i don't think that i agree with you, Mr_Tusk. a countably infinite number of discrete points will have measure zero.  there are uncountable values of real numbers in the interval $0 \le x \le 1$ and that interval has measure of 1.  i believe the fact is that in any set having measure greater than zero, the number of elements in that set is uncountably infinite.  i know you can have two (or more) sets of reals between 0 and 1 and both have uncountably infinite elements.  but i meant the set of reals between 0 and 1 where we remove the points $\frac13$, $\frac23$. then repeatedly do that to the

Comment: @robert I think your comment got cropped at some point in the middle

Comment: A realization or a sample of a 1-dimensional Brownian motion, also known as a [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process), has, at probability 1, uncountably infinitely many zeros. Maybe such would make a good starting point for a positive example.

Comment: For more ideas see Mathematics Stack Exchange: [Can Cantor set be the zero set of a continuous function?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there's no way a function's Laplace transform can have uncountably many poles. The reasoning should be based on the fact that a Laplace transform of a function must be holomorphic (which can be derived using Morera's theorem), and since its poles must be, by definition, isolated points, there must be a finite number of them for any compact subset of the transform's ROC (that's why my original idea with a function having its poles defined on the Cantor set would fail). And because of that, the total set of poles is a union of countably many finite sets - so it must be countable as well. For the z-transform, the reasoning should be the same.
The Math Stack Exchange had several related questions.

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to how you define LTI.

Far as I can tell, a time-discrete system being LTI means its in- and output are related by a countably large system of ordinary differential equations.

Since each of these transforms into a polynomial through the Laplace-, Fourier- or z-transform, the transfer function, in which ever domain it exists, is always a quotient of polynomials. Coefficients of polynomials are countable.

Since polynomials have, including their multiplicity, [exactly the number of roots as their degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), and poles are just the roots of the denominator polynomial, we'll always have countably many roots – and thus, poles.

---

Not quite sure you'd want to relax the constraint that poles be countable, anyway: If you do that, transfer functions cease to be meromorphic, and that means the residue theorem doesn't apply, and as far as I can intuit, that leads to unsolvable integrals that you'd need to define the $z$-transform to begin with...

Comment: As a German, you know well that your oriental neighbors are about 40 millions, hence countable.

Comment: The class of LTI systems is larger than the ones that are described by systems of differential (or difference) equations. As long as input and output are related by convolution, the system is LTI. E.g., in continuous-time, an ideal delay $h(t)=\delta(t-T)$ is LTI (but not described by a differential equation). In discrete time, the same is true if the delay is not an integer. Other examples of LTI systems not described by (a finite number of) differential (difference) equations are ideal filters.

Comment: @MattL. ah, I need to unwrap your comment: If the delay is not an integer, we just sum up an infinite (but countable) set of interpolation points, right, to get the coefficients that go with each integer $z$ power. that doesn't change the fact that we've got a polynomial that can only have a countable set of roots. #

Comment: I feel a bit uncomfortable with transfer functions that are a ratio of two polynomials with infinite order ... Following that logic, an ideal low pass filter should have such a transfer function. However, the corresponding power series doesn't converge, which is the reason why an ideal lowpass filter actually has no transfer function. I'm not sure though what bearing that has on the question.